# showing error on model in angular js ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, model, web-frontend

showing error on model in angular js ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
 controller
    myApp.controller('userController ',['$scope',function($scope){
    }]);

```
model app.js


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ngCookie']);    

myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl:'templates/users/login.html',
        controller:'userController'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/dashboard',{
        templateUrl:'template/users/dashboard.html',
        controller:'userController'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/logout',{
        templateUrl:'template/users/logout.html',
        controller:'userController'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise('/');
    }   

]);
```

Comment: Can you post a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is typo in module injection of `ngCookies` instead of `ngCookie`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
```

Also make sure `angular-route.js` & `angular-cookies.js` loaded after angular correctly.

Comment: @Apurva does it helped?